# How to define a variable during build with cmake?

Tags: cmake

I would like to define a CMake variable BUILD_TIME_VAR in CMakeLists.txt:

- computed with a python script during build phase
- I can then access its content with ${VAR}

In other words, the equivalent during build phase of:

```
execute_process(COMMAND bash -c "python $SCRIPT $FILE" OUTPUT_VARIABLE GEN_TIME_VAR)
```

The variable is then used to generate a file which is a dependency to make binaries.

The goal is to make the code more easy to read since otherwise, the computation occur several times.

Rather than calling n times, the python script, to compute BUILD_TIME_VAR, I would like to use the script once, to factor the code in this way:

```
 if(expression_1)
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT foo
    COMMAND cmd_1(${BUILD_TIME_VAR}))

    ...
  elseif(expression_2)
    # elseif section.
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT foo
    COMMAND cmd_2(${BUILD_TIME_VAR}))
    ...
  else(expression_n)
    # else section.
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT foo
    COMMAND cmd_n(${BUILD_TIME_VAR}))
    ...
  endif(expression)

add_custom_target(${BINARY} ALL
DEPENDS foo)
```

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking. Can you try to explain a bit more, perhaps with an example of what you'd like to do and what you're currently doing? Are you trying to set a CMake variable based on the output of a custom target?

Comment: I reformulate it. I first tred to use execute_process which permits to define OUTPUT_VARIABLE but the computations occur during generation, not during build. Then I try with add_custom_target and add_custom_command which does not propose OUTPUT_VARIABLE.

Comment: Builds happen long after CMake has finished running, so what you're asking is not possible directly. However, it smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what you're actually trying to achieve by this?

Comment: So you're effectively trying to create a build-time variable?

Comment: Yes I want to create a build-time variable. I understand it can't be a cmake variable because CMake has run before I build the file. Neverthess, when you use two COMMAND in add_custom_command, is it possible to use the result of the first one in the second one?

Comment: Not directly; CMake guarantees they will be run sequentially, but they will not be piped together or anything like that.

Comment: @captain_flammy on the update: you're not calling it `N` times; there are `N` commands, but during *generation* only **one** version of the custom command will be defined, that will be used repeatedly as need to update the custom target `foo` during the build phase. If you want to eliminate the textual repetition, you can't do much, unless the the `expression_*` can be provided as an argument to that script. But this again is useless, if it is to just move the switch statement to the external script without any further benefit, especially if it's not within the script's responsibilities.

Comment: Of course, like it is a switch, only one call, I agree. The goal was to improve readability, as mentioned initially, with a build-time variable. It seems not possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you're effectively trying to create a "build-time variable." That is something that the build tool (actually *all* the build tools supported by CMake) would have to support. I know of no such functionality in build tools (make, ninja, VS, ...), and hence of no support for such a thing in CMake either.

You could emulate this by writing the results to a file and reading that file in all subsequent build steps using it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you've misinterpreted the role of CMake. In short, CMake generates build files for the back-end system of your choice (Make, ninja, etc.). This is concisely reviewed [here](https://www.aosabook.org/en/cmake.html#fig.cma.pro), where the configure/generate step is briefly documented along with how it precedes the actual build step.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve exactly, but maybe defining custom commands and using their outputs to link them to custom targets for further dependency chaining (see `DEPENDS` [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html)) might be helpful, e.g.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(foobar)

set(FOO_FILES "foo.txt")

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${FOO_FILES}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${FOO_FILES}
  COMMAND echo hello >> ${FOO_FILES}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
  COMMENT "Creating ${FOO_FILES}"
  VERBATIM)

add_custom_target(foo DEPENDS ${FOO_FILES})

set(BAR_FILES "bar_dummy.txt") # this is only use to link the custom command to the corresponding custom target

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${BAR_FILES}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${BAR_FILES}
  COMMAND cat ${FOO_FILES}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
  COMMENT "Displaying ${FOO_FILES}"
  VERBATIM)

add_custom_target(bar DEPENDS ${BAR_FILES})

add_dependencies(bar foo)
```

However, you might need to consider the probability of going against the tool, and thus, it might be clearer to have a required step prior to the configuration of your project.

Comment: I expanded the initial post to try to be more clear. Thanks.